# How to append value within nested lapply/sapply function?

Tags: r, lapply, sapply

Is there a reason why I can't append values to an empty vector when called within a nested lapply/apply function? I have an empty vector `bucket` where I'd like to push values into, however, the output says the `bucket` is reinitialized with each iteration. I would appreciate any insight into how to what I am doing wrong.

```
head(genelist.info.u)
#                   Gene Chromosome       TSS       TES Strand ExternalGeneID
#           142     TAL1       chr1  47697387  47681962     -1           TAL1
#           294    TGFB2       chr1 218519577 218617961      1          TGFB2
#           735   SPAG17       chr1 118507433 118496484     -1         SPAG17
#           749 ANKRD34A       chr1 145470508 145475646      1       ANKRD34A
#           757    RCSD1       chr1 167599330 167675486      1          RCSD1
#           763     LHX9       chr1 197881037 197887120      1           LHX9

bucket <- vector()
newlist <- lapply(chr, FUN=function(u){
     genelist.info.u <- genelist.info[[u]]
     if(dim(genelist.info.u)[1] > 0){
          cov.chr <- sapply(1:nrow(genelist.info.u), FUN=function(x){
               if(genelist.info.u[x, "Strand"] == 1){
                    #do something
               }else{
                    #do something else
               }
               print(paste0("gene: ", genelist.info.u[x, "Gene"]))
               bucket <- c(bucket, genelist.info.u[x, "Gene"])
               print(paste0("bucket: ", bucket))
               return(gene.coverage)
          })
          return(cov.chr)
     }
})

> bucket
logical(0)

Output:
[1] "gene: TAL1"
[1] "bucket: TAL1"
[1] "gene: TGFB2"
[1] "bucket: TGFB2"
[1] "gene: SPAG17"
[1] "bucket: SPAG17"
[1] "gene: ANKRD34A"
[1] "bucket: ANKRD34A"
[1] "gene: RCSD1"
[1] "bucket: RCSD1"
[1] "gene: LHX9"
[1] "bucket: LHX9"
[1] "gene: NOTO"
[1] "bucket: NOTO"
[1] "gene: OTX1"
```

Comment: try using `bucket <<- c(bucket, genelist.info.u[x, "Gene"])` instead. I can't reproduce your code so I am not sure if that is the fix, but it seems to be the issue based on the above

Comment: Go back to basics. Just write a simple version using `for` loops. Don't grow `bucket` one element at a time, pre-allocate the vector, even if it's an over-estimate of the resulting size. Once you have that working, ways to vectorize it may become clear.

Comment: @Stephen - while this works to fix your problem, @joran is right on the money. There are simpler ways of doing this in R, and getting in the habit of using `<<-` will complicate your life as your code becomes more complex.

Comment: @Chris I've inherited someone's project, and this is simply to help troubleshoot an issue I'm having. I will definitely have to refactor as it's overly complicated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bucket` declared outside of the function and `bucket` inside of the function are not necessarily the same thing. When inside the function, your call of `bucket <- c(bucket, genelist.info.u[x, "Gene"])` updates the `bucket` in that function. Because you do not return `bucket` at the end, the one you initialized at first in the global environment (with `bucket <- vector()`) remains unchanged.

In other words, assignments made inside a function affect the environment of the function, not the global environment, unless you explicitly do things to change that.

To assign to the parent environment, use `<<-` instead of `<-`

Comment: I would add that I generally don't recommend writing functions that affect the global environment - it kind of ruins the point of functions having their own environments.